# SQLite misses characters on text retrieval

Tags: linux, sqlite, g++

I'm working on porting an app from Windows to Linux. I've managed to make everything work as it should, except for the database. Whenever I call `sqlite3_column_text16()`, I get a string which is missing most characters. I don't know where this behaviour stems from as on Windows it worked impeccably.

I'm doing nothing special, just

```
wstring a(static_cast<wchar_t const *>(sqlite3_column_text16(stmt, 2)));
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unicode characters can have more than 16 bits, so all operating systems except Windows use a 32-bit type for `wchar_t`.

You could convert from UTF-16 to UTF-32 (take care of surrogate pairs), but depending on how your program is designed, it might be easier just to use UTF-8 everywhere.